# Android Studio: Run tab does not display flutter logs - Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, flutter

Android Studio: 3.3
OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Run tab does not display any logs when main.dart is run.

Although logs get displayed when a test is run.

[image: Blank Run Tab]

I've tried checking and unchecking the '*Replace the Run and Debug console output with an experimental Flutter Logging view* ' option under **Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > Experiments** with no success.

Comment: With "logs" do you mean the output of the `print` function? Are you running your app on the emulator or on a real device? If it's a real device is that  device a Huawei model?

Comment: Yes. Output of the `print` function. Also, the device isn't Huawei. I tried on two different handsets one of which is a Xiaomi Mi A1.

Comment: Try on the emulator and see if it works. Many real devices has log printing disabled (like Huawei) and you need to explicitly enable them (how you do it differs from device to device)

Comment: Just tried.. Still nothing.

Comment: See also if [this](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs) could be of any help. Actually It didn't happen to me, so, I'm out of hints.

Comment: Same issue here! Still no solution? :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although I use macOS, following operation solved the same problem:

rm ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.3/options/runner.layout.xml
and then, reboot the Android Studio.

I hope this will be helpful:)

Cheers,

[image: 1.Before]

[image: 2.Change directory]

[image: 3.delete runner.layout.xml]

[image: 4.Yay!]

Comment: This should be accepted as answer! it worked for me.

Comment: according to https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config `runner.layout.xml` also can be at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio<yourversion>`

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find `runner.layout.xml`: If you have the same problem you can:

Go to the menu bar of Android Studio window,

Press `Window->Restore default layout`

[image: Where to click on Android Studio]

Comment: I can't run Flutter in release mode on a device and show logs. I will update when I know how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the .idea and build folder then again build and run the main.dart. Hopefully now the logs will show.